# Changing the margin of an XAML object with C#

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012

Need help with this problem.

I initialize a text box in MainPage.xaml with

```
<TextBox 
    x:Name="box"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    TextWrapping="NoWrap"
    Text="TextBox"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    RenderTransformOrigin="1.332,-26.438"
    Height="23" Width="1366"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
</TextBox>
```

then I try to change the margin in MainPage.xaml.cs with:

`box.Margin = new Thickness(0,grid.Height - 23,0,0);`

This is the runtime error

```
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
occurred in Console.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from
a call to a COM component.
```

And here's an image to show the margin changing code and the error: http://screencast.com/t/U7pzizHzb

Comment: Can you please post your code and explain the problem in words. BTW `thing.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, right, bottom);` should work.

Comment: Did it, lemme know what you think

Comment: You called your application "Console"? (from comment on deleted answer) - that doesn't sound sensible. Also are you sure that a blank application can have a graphical UI? It's not been the case in previous versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Although grid.ActualHeight is the most appropriate in this case, I think that the error is not related to the Height or Margin property.

Comment: blank application just pregenerates the code blank and ready to add stuff. also, once I comment-out the line that attempts to change the box margins, it runs just fine and puts the box in the middle of the screen, just like the initialization code should.

Comment: Which UI framework -- WPF, Silverlight, or WinRT? Given the unhelpful COM error, I'm guessing WinRT (i.e., Windows 8 Metro-style app), but you didn't specify.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're making this overly complex. The margin you're setting will result in the TextBox being bottom-aligned and forced to be exactly 23 pixels high. So why not just do that to begin with?

```
<TextBox ... Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

I'm not 100% sure what's causing your COM error, but my first guess would be that your "manually change the Margin" code is running at a point in time when the UI framework isn't ready for such changes. (I've found WinRT to be quite fragile that way.) So removing the codebehind, and specifying your layout in XAML, is likely to fix your COM error, as well as making your code simpler and easier to maintain.

Comment: What do you mean by "removing the codebehind"? Can you please specify?